# Persian and Arabic Support for Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code does not seem to display Persian or Arabic scripts nicely in the terminal window. I can confirm that on Linux, but not sure about macOS or Windows. Instead of displaying right-to-left languages from right to left, it chains characters to each other from left to right. I tried changing its terminal to one with good Persian support like Konsole from the settings, but it didn't work. Is there a way to solve this or do we have to request project maintainers to add the support?

A screen shot is attached to show the problem. [image]

Comment: How did you try to change the terminal? For me, `"externalConsole": true` in launch.json works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems use the package linked below. You can use it to first convert the text and copy that and paste it into the terminal for input. I made it to correctly organize the Arabic characters and display them correctly. The library supports,
Arabic, Farsi, and English characters and symbols.
Check it out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtl-arabic